# Conditional List Looping in JasperReport

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

if size of the list is greater than 2, there will be another attachment(another template) file for that list.

```
<![CDATA[$P{policyInsuredPersonBeneficiariesList}.size() < 3]]>
```

Report :

```
<parameter name="policyInsuredPersonBeneficiariesList" class="java.util.List"/>
.....
<componentElement>
    <reportElement uuid="e7c57647-5643-443f-bc07-c0e4ff6c5392" x="124" y="412" width="140" height="18" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true">
        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$P{policyInsuredPersonBeneficiariesList}.size() > 2]]></printWhenExpression>
    </reportElement>
    <jr:list xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" printOrder="Vertical" ignoreWidth="false">
        <datasetRun subDataset="dsInsuredPersonBeneficiaries" uuid="03295256-f4a3-4bd9-85bf-7a01896a544b">
            <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($P{policyInsuredPersonBeneficiariesList})]]></dataSourceExpression>
        </datasetRun>
        <jr:listContents height="18" width="140">
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement uuid="8a76ba89-7f02-4755-86d0-c9789925bf2a" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="0" y="1" width="140" height="15"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Zawgyi-One" size="10"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{fullName}+" - "+$F{percentage}+"% - "+((org.ace.insurance.system.common.relationship.RelationShip)$F{relationship}).getName()]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </jr:listContents>
    </jr:list>
</componentElement>
```

I always get the following exception :

```
1) generateLifePolicyIssueSingle(org.ace.insurance.report.test.ReportTest)
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 2
    at java.util.ArrayList.RangeCheck(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.remove(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Collections$SynchronizedList.remove(Unknown Source)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint.removePage(JasperPrint.java:535)
```

BTW : I use JasperReport 5.1

Comment: Is it possible that you are modifying the *List* (which storing in *$P{policyInsuredPersonBeneficiariesList}*) after calling the exporter?

Comment: @Alex K, I did not modify, I just pass the list as parameter.

Comment: Please separate the List size information in a separated variable(if possible). So with the variable is easy to check the value before compare inside a IF clause. Figure out the life-cycle when the list is populated versus the sub-report/band you are calling the expression.